# Unity 2D import sprites larger than their original size

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

So, I made a sprite that is half long an HD screen, but when I import that in Unity and I add it to the scene it's larger than half the screen. I already set the camera resolution to 1920x1080. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the size of image that matters, but the container in which it is to be placed. Adjust the size of your Image using Rect Tool and Rect Transform.